# Google Kubernetes Engine: NetworkPolicy allowing egress to k8s-metadata-proxy

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-networkpolicy

**Context**

I have a Google Kubernetes Engine (GKE) cluster with [Workload Identity](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/workload-identity) enabled. As part of Workload Identity, a [k8s-metadata-proxy](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/k8s-metadata-proxy) DaemonSet runs on the cluster. I have a namespace `my-namespace` and want to deny all egress traffic of pods in the namespace except egress to the k8s-metadata-proxy DaemonSet. As such I have the following NetworkPolicy:

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: test-network-policy
  namespace: my-namespace
spec:
  # Apply to all pods.
  podSelector: {}
  policyTypes:
  - Egress
  egress:
  - ports:
    # This is needed to whitelist k8s-metadata-proxy. See https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/k8s-metadata-proxy
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 988
```

**Problem**

The NetworkPolicy is too broad because it allows egress TCP traffic to *any host* on port 988 instead of just egress to the k8s-metadata-proxy DaemonSet, but I can't seem to find a way to specify the `.spec.egress[0].to` to achieve the granularity I want.

I have tried the following `to`s:

```yaml
  egress:
  - to:
    - namespaceSelector:
        matchLabels:
          namespace: kube-system
    ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 988
  - to:
    - ipBlock:
        cidr: <cidr of pod IP range>
    - ipBlock:
        cidr: <cidr of services IP range>
    ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 988
```

but these rules result in traffic to the k8s-metadata-proxy being blocked.

**Question**

How can I select the k8s-metadata-proxy DaemonSet in the `to` part of an egress rule in a `networking.k8s.io/v1/NetworkPolicy`?

Comment: Hello. You can add to your `Egress` definition `podSelector.matchLabels` to allow your pod to connect only to the `Pods` with specific `label`. You can read more about it here: https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/network-policy#step_3_restrict_outgoing_traffic_from_the_pods

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said in the comment:

> Hello. You can add to your Egress definition podSelector.matchLabels to allow your pod to connect only to the Pods with specific label. You can read more about it here: [cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/…](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/network-policy#step_3_restrict_outgoing_traffic_from_the_pods)

**This comment could be misleading as the communication with `gke-metadata-server` is described in the official documentation:**

- *[Cloud.google.com: Kubernetes Engine: Workload Identity: GKE-MDS](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/workload-identity#gke_mds)*

Focusing on the part of above documentation:

> ### Understanding the GKE metadata server
>
> The GKE metadata server is a new [metadata server](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/storing-retrieving-metadata) designed for use with Kubernetes. It runs as a [daemonset](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/daemonset) , with one Pod on each cluster node. The metadata server intercepts HTTP requests to http://metadata.google.internal (`169.254.169.254:80`), including requests like `GET /computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/default/token` to retrieve a token for the Google service account the Pod is configured to act as. Traffic to the metadata server never leaves the VM instance that hosts the Pod.
>
> **Note**: If you have a strict [cluster network policy](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/network-policy) in place, you must allow egress to 127.0.0.1/32 on port 988 so your Pod can communicate with the GKE metadata server.

The rule to allow traffic only to `GKE Metadata server` is described in the last paragraph of above citation. The `YAML` definition should look like below:

```yaml
kind: NetworkPolicy
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: egress-rule
  namespace: restricted-namespace # <- namespace your pod is in 
spec:
  policyTypes:
  - Egress
  podSelector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx # <- label used by pods trying to communicate with metadata server
  egress:
  - to:
    - ipBlock:
        cidr: 127.0.0.1/32 # <- allow communication with metadata server #1 
  - ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 988 # <- allow communication with metadata server #2
```

---

Assuming that:

- You have a Kubernetes cluster with:

  - `Network Policy` enabled
  - `Workload Identity` enabled
- Your `Pods` are trying to communicate from `restricted-namespace` namespace

The output for describing needed `NetworkPolicy`:

- `$ kubectl describe networkpolicy -n restricted-namespace egress-rule`

```sh
Name:         egress-rule
Namespace:    restricted-namespace
Created on:   2020-10-04 18:31:10 +0200 CEST
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration:
                {"apiVersion":"networking.k8s.io/v1","kind":"NetworkPolicy","metadata":{"annotations":{},"name":"egress-rule","namespace":"restricted-name...
Spec:
  PodSelector:     app=nginx
  Allowing ingress traffic:
    <none> (Selected pods are isolated for ingress connectivity)
  Allowing egress traffic:
    To Port: <any> (traffic allowed to all ports)
    To:
      IPBlock:
        CIDR: 127.0.0.1/32
        Except: 
    ----------
    To Port: 988/TCP
    To: <any> (traffic not restricted by source)
  Policy Types: Egress
```

> **Disclaimer!**
>
> Applying those rules will deny all the traffic from pods with `app=nginx` label  not destined to the metadata server!

You can create and `exec` into the pod with a label `app=nginx` by:

```sh
kubectl run -it --rm nginx \
--image=nginx \
--labels="app=nginx" \
--namespace=restricted-namespace \
-- /bin/bash
```

> **Tip!**
>
> Image `nginx` is used as it's having `curl` installed by default!

> By this example you won't be able to communicate with DNS server. You can either:
>
> - allow your pods to communicate with DNS server
> - set the `env` variable for metadata server (169.254.169.254)

Example of communicating with `GKE Metadata Server`:

- `$ curl 169.254.169.254/computeMetadata/v1/instance/ -H 'Metadata-Flavor: Google'`

```sh
attributes/
hostname
id
service-accounts/
zone
```

---

Additional resources:

- *[Cloud.google.com: Compute: Storing retrieving metadata](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/storing-retrieving-metadata)*

---

---

To allow specific pods to send traffic only to the specific pods on specific ports you can use following policy:

```yaml
kind: NetworkPolicy
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: egress-rule
  namespace: restricted-namespace # <- namespace of "source" pod
spec:
  policyTypes:
  - Egress
  podSelector:
    matchLabels:
      app: ubuntu # <- label for "source" pod
  egress:
  - to:
    - podSelector:
        matchLabels:
          app: nginx # <- label for "destination" pod
  - ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80 # <- allow only port 80
```

Comment: Thanks, whitelisting 127.0.0.1:988 as per the documentation you linked works

Comment: They should make it more visible in the official document.